# Fast way to find nonzero elements positions in 2d array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, 2d

The reason why I create this question is that I think numpy.nonzero function is not as optimized as it should. The following example shows this fact:

```
a=np.random.random((1000,1000))
a[a<0.5]=0
timeit.timeit(lambda:np.nonzero(a),number=100)/100.0
#gives 0.014248089790344238 secs 
timeit.timeit(lambda:np.nonzero(a>0),number=100)/100.0
#gives 0.010561790466308594 secs
```

I don't understand the fact why this happens, as I believe that both lines produce the same result for every input, whatever the dtype, thus I name it a bug, correct me if wrong. Anyways, there is a severe lack of optimization. Another way to increase the speed of finding nonzero elements is , if the function is called multiple times, the size of the input array is static and the array is sparse, to create a 3d array holding all the positions of the input array and then perform boolean slicing of this array, using the corresponding mask, ie:

```
def check_speed(a,positions,thres):
    a[a<thres]=0
    print 'Thresholding at:',thres
    print '\t Number of nonzero elements:',np.sum(a>0)
    print '\t Using numpy nonzero:', timeit.timeit(lambda:np.transpose(np.nonzero(a)),number=100)/100.0, 's'
    print '\t Using improved numpy nonzero:', timeit.timeit(lambda:np.transpose(np.nonzero(a>0)),number=100)/100.0, 's'
    print '\t Using readily made matrix:', timeit.timeit(lambda:positions[a>0],number=100)/100.0 ,'s'

a=np.random.random((1000,1000))
positions = np.transpose(np.nonzero(np.ones_like(a))).reshape(a.shape + (2,))
check_speed(a,positions,0.5)
check_speed(a,positions,0.8)
check_speed(a,positions,0.9)
check_speed(a,positions,0.995)
check_speed(a,positions,0.998)
check_speed(a,positions,0.999)
check_speed(a,positions,0.9995)
```

with result:

```
Thresholding at: 0.5
     Number of nonzero elements: 499248
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.0171903395653 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.0139024186134 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.0163935399055 s    
Thresholding at: 0.8
     Number of nonzero elements: 199189
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.0108882308006 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00774354934692 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00900489091873 s
Thresholding at: 0.9
     Number of nonzero elements: 99493
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.00896275043488 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00562391996384 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00671306848526 s
Thresholding at: 0.995
     Number of nonzero elements: 4849
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.00732887983322 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00353765010834 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00311932086945 s
Thresholding at: 0.998
     Number of nonzero elements: 1930
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.00729090929031 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00361618041992 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00302290916443 s
Thresholding at: 0.999
     Number of nonzero elements: 959
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.00952008008957 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00364511966705 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00303998947144 s
Thresholding at: 0.9995
     Number of nonzero elements: 490
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.00758473873138 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00350986003876 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.0028409409523 s
```

Below 10000 nonzero elements in a 1000*1000 array the method seems to give faster results. I guess this happens because there is a bottleneck between memory manipulation and calculations. There was no reason to research scipy equivalents, as by experience scipy is terribly slow relatively to numpy module. So, my question is:

Does anyone know of a better way to find nonzero elements positions inside an array? Thank you beforehand for your answers.

## **Update with answer**

Collaborating with @Roxanne 's answer:

```
def check_speed(a,positions,thres):
    a[a<thres]=0
    print 'Thresholding at:',thres
    print '\t Number of nonzero elements:',np.sum(a>0)
    print '\t Using cv2:', timeit.timeit(lambda:np.fliplr(cv2.findNonZero((a>0).astype(np.uint8)).squeeze()),number=100)/100.0, 's'
    print '\t Using numpy nonzero:', timeit.timeit(lambda:np.transpose(np.array(np.nonzero(a))),number=100)/100.0, 's'
    print '\t Using improved numpy nonzero:', timeit.timeit(lambda:np.transpose(np.nonzero(a>0)),number=100)/100.0, 's'
    print '\t Using readily made matrix:', timeit.timeit(lambda:positions[a>0],number=100)/100.0 ,'s'
a=np.random.random((1000,1000))
positions = np.transpose(np.nonzero(np.ones_like(a))).reshape(a.shape + (2,))
a[a<0.5]=0
check_speed(a,positions,0.5)
check_speed(a,positions,0.8)
check_speed(a,positions,0.9)
check_speed(a,positions,0.995)
check_speed(a,positions,0.998)
check_speed(a,positions,0.999)
check_speed(a,positions,0.9995)
```

which gives:

```
Thresholding at: 0.5
     Number of nonzero elements: 499806
     Using cv2: 0.00592091083527 s
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.0176041412354 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.0138215017319 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.0165240502357 s
Thresholding at: 0.8
     Number of nonzero elements: 200022
     Using cv2: 0.00379456996918 s
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.0111160302162 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00776970148087 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00905373096466 s
Thresholding at: 0.9
     Number of nonzero elements: 99835
     Using cv2: 0.00287639141083 s
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.00894243955612 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00543779850006 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00669163942337 s
Thresholding at: 0.995
     Number of nonzero elements: 4931
     Using cv2: 0.00203591108322 s
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.00747500181198 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00370697021484 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00331105947495 s
Thresholding at: 0.998
     Number of nonzero elements: 2018
     Using cv2: 0.00203846931458 s
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.00735512971878 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.0036293721199 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00307144880295 s
Thresholding at: 0.999
     Number of nonzero elements: 1038
     Using cv2: 0.00200258970261 s
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.00735764026642 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00369818925858 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00302011013031 s
Thresholding at: 0.9995
     Number of nonzero elements: 521
     Using cv2: 0.0019414305687 s
     Using numpy nonzero: 0.00776562213898 s
     Using improved numpy nonzero: 0.00395655155182 s
     Using readily made matrix: 0.00321444988251 s
```

This is by far the best result I have seen using Python.

Comment: Look up `nonzero` in the github source code. It's relatively simple `c` code. There may be a separate handling of Boolean values. It also calls a count nonzero to allocate space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked `cv2.findNonZero` was faster than `numpy.nonzero`. But you may need to make some conversions, which are: `np.fliplr(cv2.findNonZero((a>0).astype(np.uint8)).squeeze())`

Comment: `where` uses `nonzero`

Comment: @Roxanne Oh you are the best, `np.fliplr(cv2.findNonZero((a>0).astype(np.uint8)).squeeze()` does what I want more than 2 times faster most times! Never thought to look up C++ documentation for OpenCV to find this awesome function. I will update my question with your answer and benchmarks